# Aspose Sort Cells based on Row as Key in java

Tags: java, sorting, aspose, aspose-cells

I have an Excel File with Some Columns merged as shown in the Screen Shot,
I want to Sort the TOP Columns in ascending order and their Corresponding values, and then I'll sort the `COLUMN1, COLUMN2, Column3`, But Before I want to Sort the TOP Column Headers, For Eg: `TOP COLUMN A` should Come first and the Corresponding `Sub column` and the values of those Six TOP columns.

Content area I was able to sort, but how will I be able to achieve Sorting for the TOP Cols Headers?

[image: BEFORE]

[image: AFTER]

Comment: Aspose.Cells can sort Data with one column and with multiple columns. We can share some simple sample code which you can run at your end and modify it as per your needs..

Comment: hi @shakeel I wanr to sort data from left to right for level1 as row1 and level2 as row2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, you want to sort data from left to right, you need to set the following property to true.

```
Workbook.getDataSorter().setSortLeftToRight(true);
```

Please see the following code. **It sorts data from left to right by row 3**. You can add more levels too.

**Java**

```
// Load your Excel file
Workbook wb = new Workbook(dirPath + "sort.xlsx");

// For the first key, we want to sort by assending order
// And we want to sort by row not by column
// using SortLeftToRight property
wb.getDataSorter().setOrder1(SortOrder.ASCENDING);
wb.getDataSorter().setSortLeftToRight(true);

// Access first worksheet
Worksheet ws = wb.getWorksheets().get(0);

// Specify the range of cells
CellArea ca = CellArea.createCellArea("A1", "I7");

// We want to sort by row 3, since index starts from 0
// So 2 means 3
wb.getDataSorter().setKey1(2);

// Sort the workbook data
wb.getDataSorter().sort(ws.getCells(), ca);

// Save the output Excel file
wb.save(dirPath + "output.xlsx");
```

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose

Comment: adding morelevels are not working , I'm trying to do `setKey2(3)` but its notreflecting , Am i doing it wrong  ?